# Echo table with special chars from database

Tags: php

I have a database table with special characters like ă â î ş ţ and I am trying to echo the table correctly with all the special characters.

I used this:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>`

And I used this code:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $legatura);

mb_language('uni');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'",$conn); 
mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $conn);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $conn); 
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $conn);
```

But I only get "?" and "�" where the special characters are.

The database and the tables from it are in collation: utf_8_unicode_ci

Comment: Are you sure they are saved in UTF8 inside database?

Comment: @frlan yes i am sure:( I try almost every tutorial but is not working

Comment: � is a sure-fire sign that you are using UTF-8, but feeding it invalid character data that is not UTF-8

Comment: @Pekka웃: Yepp, that's why I was asking. If you are reading UTF8 data to e.g. latin it would look like Ã¼ for German Umlaut ü

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all it worked with this

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: Your question states that you already had this in your html. So how could it have solved the problem?